# Modifications failed installing rdlc report designer in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, rdlc

I am trying to install Microsoft RDLC Report Designer in Visual Studio 2017. For my install attempt I went to Tools--> Extensions and Updates and selected RDLC Report Designer and clicked download.  It began the installation process and then failed with a Modifications Failed box shown on the attached see screen shot. I also tried to install the RDLC Report Designer from the Marketplace and got the same error. Any idea why this is happening? I have Visual Studio 2013 installed on the same machine with RLDC installed for it, could that be the problem?[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtiRs.jpg)

The only things I saw in the installation log that stood out were:

Capping recursion at 5 directories in each extension root due to 'default limit'.
5/2/2022 12:35:06 PM - Skipping 'C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Microsoft SDKs' as it doesn't exist
5/2/2022 12:35:06 PM - The extension with ID '717ad572-c4b7-435c-c166-c2969777f718' is not installed to Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017.

Thanks

Pete

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the RDLC Report Designer and Report Server Project installed by updating visual studio and then installing the extensions.

Pete